# Installing jdk 8 on a fresh Linux Mint 18.2

Tags: java, linux, linux-mint

On a newly installed Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64 bit distribution, typing in Terminal:

```
java -version
```

gives the following results:

```bash
% java -version  
The program "java" can be found in the following packages:  
*   default-jre
*   gcj-5-jre-headless
*   openjdk-8-jre-headless
*   gcj-4.8-jre-headless
*   gcj-4.9-jre-headless
*   openjdk-9-jre-headless
```

Is it mandatory to remove all packets mentioned above before installing jdk 8 on Linux Mint 18.2 64 bit?

Comment: What're the results you are talking about?

Comment: "gives some results" provides exactly zero information. And what are the packages mentioned above? And why would you remove them?

Comment: Thank you, I completed the question.

Answer (score 1):

Linux Mint 18.2 and above I believe the default JDK is version 8.

The easiest way to install it is go to `Menu->Administration->Software Manager` and search for `JDK`. Install the `Default-jdk`, or you can look for the `Openjdk-8-jdk`. Also install the `-doc` too if you need that.

EDIT: from either the Software Manager or the Synaptic Package Manager you can remove any older versions.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to deinstall the existing jdk, just download, unzip and install any version you'd like. Like so:

```
cd /my/download/location/for/java/zip/file
unzip java-zip-file.zip
mv java-unzipped-folder /some/path/to/your/java/versions/.
```

..and update your `.bashrc`-file or `.profile`-file to include the newest java-version